# Phone won`t boot into android/recovery

Tags: adb, boot-loop, unbricking

android phone won't boot into os/recovery even after flashing a new ones.
here`s adb logcat maybe something writen here https://pastebin.com/6bSFURBM

Comment: Hello. Which Android phone are you using? What did you flash and how did you flash it? Have you tried flashing stock ROM? Or, is the phone bricked and simply does not boot up?

Comment: +1 for providing logcat